# Display the articles of a category by role

Tags: categories, user-roles

In our intranet we have 120 locations => 120 groups => 120 Categories and 120 authors.
in the home page we want to display a carousel, where we will show post's titles (with link) according to the group
For example, the group1 will see a carousel with articles from category1, group2 will see a carousel with articles from category2 ....
Of course, authors will continue to feed their categories, how will stored in the carousel by date

Any idea about who can I do that ?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. What kind of content locations and groups are? Are they custom post types, custom taxonomies? Is group a custom user role? Authors are presumably users with Author role, right?

Comment: Thank you for your response/questions - We want to create a Category per city (eg: News NY, News Miami, ...), we have an author per city, for users they are dispatched on roles (NY_users, Miami_users,...) but all of them are subscribers - please tell me if you need more details

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to have some kind of lookup table, either hard coded or as a [settings page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API), where you map role (user group) to category (city). Then use the [current user object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/) to get city based role and use it as a key to get a category ID from the lookup table, which you use in your [post query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters).

Pseudo-code example,

```
// Current user data
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
// Get city role
$city_based_role = some_function_to_get_city_role_from_roles($current_user->roles);
// Get category id
$city_category = some_function_to_get_category_id_from_role_to_category_lookup_table($city_based_role);
// Query posts for category
$args = array(
  // some args
  'cat' => $city_category,
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```